# Deleted entities show up as modified in Entity Framework Core's ChangeTracker

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to understand why Entity Framework Core 2's ChangeTracker sets the state of deleted entities to 'modified' if the deletion is done by removing the entity from a list in another entity.

Consider this example:

```
Class1
  List<Class2> MyListOfClass2Objects

Class2
```

Both classes have their own `DbSet` in EF's `DbContext`. If I remove an object from the `MyListOfClass2Objects` list and then call `DbContext.SaveChanges()`, the state of the `Class2` object in `ChangeTracker` is set to `EntityState.Modified`, and not `EntityState.Deleted`, which I would expect. If I delete the entity by calling `Set<T>.Remove()` the state in the `ChangeTracker` is `EntityState.Deleted`. In both cases however, the entity is removed from the database.

So, why does Entity Framework set different values in ChangeTracker depending on how you delete an entity even though it is really deleted in both cases?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:** At the end (thanks to [@Sebastian finding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49479113/deleted-entities-show-up-as-modified-in-entity-framework-cores-changetracker/49479306#comment86014607_49479306)) it turns out to be a known issue with the current (at the time of writing) EF Core implementation, tracked originally by [EF Core marks entities removed From child collections as modified #10093](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/10093#issuecomment-337671369). The short explanation is:

> because cascade deletes happens *while SaveChanges is running* which means in your code will not see this state as it looks at the state before SaveChanges has executed

and

> Cascade delete happens as part of SaveChanges.
>
> Fixup of non-deleted entities to no longer reference deleted entities happens after SaveChanges.

The currently associated action item is [Allow delete fixup and cascade timing to be configured #10114](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/10114), unfortunately in backlog, i.e. unknown if and when will be addressed.

**Original:**

Because when you remove an entity from the corresponding `DbSet`, you are telling EF that you want to delete it. But when you remove it from the parent entity collection, if the relationship is **optinal** (as it seems to be in your case), EF treats that as attempt to disassociate the child from the parent (same as setting `child.Parent` to `null`), hence it sets the FK and parent navgigation property to `null` and marks the entity as `Modified`. If you really want to delete it, you should use the first method.

All this is explained in the [Removing relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/related-data#removing-relationships) section of the documentation:

> You can remove a relationship by setting a reference navigation to null, or removing the related entity from a collection navigation.
>
> Removing a relationship can have side effects on the dependent entity, according to the cascade delete behavior configured in the relationship.
>
> By default, for required relationships, a cascade delete behavior is configured and the child/dependent entity will be deleted from the database. For optional relationships, cascade delete is not configured by default, but the foreign key property will be set to null.

Comment: So, I'll have to delete in the DbSet if this is needed. I understand your well-written explanation in general, but I'm still not certain why I see this behavior in my case. The primary and foreign keys of my entities are not nullable and thus the relationship between them is be required.  Cascade delete also works with my entities.

Comment: So you are saying the relationship is required with cascade delete turned on? That would be strange (or bug). Let me check if I can reproduce...

Comment: Yeah, you are right. The strange thing is that `SaveChanges` really deletes it. But the state was `Modified` and reference navigation property was set to `null` (but FK remains unchanged). I somehow missed that from your post. Makes no logical sense to me, may be post a question to their tracker?

Comment: I will ask the Entity Framework team about this! In the meantime, I'll have to work around the problem by always deleting entities through DbContext, which is not optimal, as this means adding references to my repositories in places I don't want them. I use the ChangeTracker to store changes in a list and later notify other parts of my application of these changes by firing events if the call SaveChanges() was successful.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, @Ivan Stoev!

Comment: I've found an issue on GitHub in which this is discussed as well: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/10093#issuecomment-337671369 The underlying problem is that cascading deletes are done by SaveChanges() and not before. It might be possible that my desired behavior will be implemented, but we'll see when this is actually the case.

Comment: Still strange though, because this isn't really a cascade operation. But good catch! Unfortunately as I see, it won't be in the 2.1 (Q2 which means between Apr and Jun this year), and actually is unknown if it's going to be addressed or not, and when.

Comment: This has been fixed in ef core 3: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/pull/14470